# Omnet++: Simultaneously send messages from more than one node

Tags: networking, simulation, omnet++

I want to animate a node receiving messages from three different nodes in OMNET++. Right now the nodes send in a sequential manner. But, I want the nodes to send messages to the root node simultaneously. Root node is occupied with an array of input gates. Is it possible in Omnet?

Answer (score 2):

You can configure the 3 nodes to send the messages at the same time by scheduling messages to be sent at the same time using the scheduleAt() function. The simulation will always show that they are transmitted sequentially, but check the T (event time) value in the simulation window. If the T value is the same every time any of the 3 messages are being sent, it means they are sent simultaneously.

The messages arriving to the root node can't be processed at the same time. Every node, including the root node, implements the handleMessage() function which will analyze each incoming message individually.

I hope this is the answer you were looking for.

Comment: Yes. The value of T is the same and I have been using scheduleAt() function. It was definitely the answer I was looking for.But, still isn't there any way I can show simultaneous simulation. If there is a way, it would have been awesome

Comment: I was troubled by this same issue about a month ago, but I didn't find a solution. If you do however find a way to do it, please let me know :)

Comment: You can only do broadcast animations (i.e. messages sent ot from the same node at the same simulation time will be animated in a parallel way). All other messages (even if they are sent at the same time) are animated sequentially.

Answer (score -1):

You have to define parameter id in ned file. In initialize set the condition `if(getIndex==id)`, send the message. Same message will be send to the node simultaneously.